# DOS command to move all files in subdirectories one level up without overwriting same file name, unique size

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, move

MY QUESTION:

I have the same situation as Rishi.  I have a number of versions of the same song by the same artist that appear on different CD's.  If I use the batch command as written, will DOS overwrite songs with the same name, even if the file size is different for each unique file?

PREVIOUS QUESTION:  DOS command to move all files in subdirectories one level up

REFERENCE Rishi asked the question on Jan 15th:

"I have a folder with a lot of sub folders with one or more files in each. I am trying to write a batch file that moves all those files to C:\songs (for example).

C:>FOR /R C:\Test %i IN (*) DO MOVE %i C:\Songs
The folders Test and songs exist, but I get an error saying

%i was unexpected at this time. 
What am I doing wrong?"

ANSWER WAS

"FOR /R %i IN (C:\Test*) DO MOVE "%i" C:\Songs
In a batch file, it has to be %%i. Weird quirk of batch."

Answer (score 0):

Within a given folder there can only be one version of a file with a given name. When executed within a batch, the MOVE command will automatically overwrite any pre-existing file of the same name. So the answer to your question is - YES, a file with the same name will be over-written, even if it has a different file size. (Note - if you are using Windows XP then you are not using DOS)

You can prevent a batch move from overwriting an existing file by piping N to MOVE with the -y option:

```
echo n | move /-y "%%~i" "C:\songs\"
```

If you want to copy and preserve both versions into the same folder, then at least one version will have to be renamed. You will have to decide what kind of naming scheme you want to use before you can begin coming up with a solution.